# Long link vs Short link for seo

Tags: html, seo, hyperlink

I'm working on a website and I'm not sure what link structure is best to use for seo.

What google would rank better?

> `domain.com/users/username` or `domain.com/u/username`
>
> `domain.com/video/video-id` or `domain.com/v/video-id`

I also see many websites include ".html" at the end, does it really work those days?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. SEO questions are better suited at **[Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)**. Please be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/about) and to search the site before asking your question as SEO has been covered in depth there.

Answer (score 2):

Keep these factors in mind to make your URLs more search engine friendly:

URLs should not contain extraneous characters ( $ @ ! * % = ? )

Shorter URLS typically rank better than longer ones

Numbers and letters should only be used in URLs.

Do not use underscores. Search engines prefer dashes.

Sub-domains can rank better than sub directories.